How to add filter on parent div using in React.js?
I have testData array. Now I'm adding filter, this is working fine but inside the box only like if there is display: "N" then the object should not be display, this is working fine but there is a issue like if there is all the objects with display: "N" inside types[] array then parent-wrapper div should not display.
Code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script type="text/babel" data-presets="react,stage-3">
    const Example = () => {
     
       const testData = [
    {
        name: "Wrapper One",
        types: [
            {
                id: "0",
                type: "Type One",
                display: "Y"
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                type: "Type Two",
                display: "N"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Wrapper Two",
        types: [
          {
            id: "0",
            type: "Type One",
            display: "N"
        },
        ]
    },
]
     
      return (
        <div>
         {testData?.map((ele: any, index: any) => (
    <div key={index} className="parent-wrapper" style={{background:'gray', marginBottom:'20px'}}>
      <h1>{ele.name}</h1>
    {ele.types.map((data: any, index: number) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  {(data?.display === "Y") ?
                  <p>{data.type}</p>
                  : null}
                </div>
     ))}
     </div>
     ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
    root.render(<Example />);
  </script>
</body>

</html>




Create a function that accepts an object's types array that checks to see if some of the type display values are set to Y, and then use that to determine whether your parent component should be displayed.
Note: because the function doesn't rely on any internal state it can be placed outside of the component/imported from a helper file etc.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script type="text/babel" data-presets="react,stage-3">

    function someTypesVisible(types) {
      return types.some(type => {
        return type.display === 'Y';
      });
    }

  const Example = () => {
     
    const testData = [
      {
        name: "Wrapper One",
        types: [
          {
            id: "0",
            type: "Type One",
            display: "Y"
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            type: "Type Two",
            display: "N"
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Wrapper Two",
        types: [
          {
            id: "0",
            type: "Type One",
            display: "N"
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
          
    return (
      <div>
        {testData?.map((ele: any, index: any) => 
          someTypesVisible(ele.types) ? (
              <div key={index} className="parent-wrapper" style={{background:'gray', marginBottom:'20px'}}>
                <h1>{ele.name}</h1>
                {ele.types.map((data: any, index: number) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                    {data?.display === 'Y' ? <p>{data.type}</p> : null}
                  </div>
                ))}
                </div>
            ) : null
        )}
      </div>
    );
    
  };
  
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  root.render(<Example />);
</script>

  </body>
</html>



